# How to fetch json inside json inside another json?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, android-json

I am new to android and json. I want to implement some logic where i can get the data from **sub1** from json inside json inside another json.
Is there any way to get that data?

This is how my **json file** looks like.

```
{
  "Aeronautical": [],
  "Automobile": [],
  "Civil": [],
  "Computer": [
    {
      "sub1": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "name1",
          "year": "2019",
          "url": "some_url"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "Name 2",
          "year": "2018",
          "url": "some url"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "name": "Name 4",
          "year": "2018",
          "url": "some url"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at proper json parsing, for example via gson?

Comment: @JakobF no. i am new here.

Comment: To clarify some terminology, JSON is a character format for transferring data between machines and applications. So saying "json inside json inside another json" doesn't make much sense because JSON itself is not a syntactical construct. Rather, it specifies the syntax for several data types: simple types for numbers and strings and aggregate types for arrays and objects. What you have here is an object which in turn has arrays and other objects nested inside.

Comment: With that said, you need a parsing library to help you get the data you want from this JSON object, Greg Moens' answer should point you in the right direction. For further help, google "JSON android" to find more tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sub1 is inside another array , so first you should get data from computer array

```
   JSONObject obj = null;
        try {
            obj = new JSONObject(json);

        JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("Computer");

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject obj_computers = arr.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray sub1 = obj_computers.getJSONArray("sub1");

            for (int j = 0; j < sub1 .length(); j++)
            {
                JSONObject sub1_data = sub1.getJSONObject(j);
                Log.i("test" ,sub1_data.toString());
            }
        }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The Android SDK includes the org.json lib. You can use the JSONObject class.

```
String jsonString = /* obtain some JSON however you need to*/;
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject sub1 = root.getJSONObject("sub1");
```

I omitted exception handling, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: I tried my logic. here's code: `try {
                            JSONObject jsonDept = response.getJSONObject(dept);
                            JSONObject jsonSub = jsonDept.getJSONObject(sub);
                            JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonSub.getJSONArray(sub);
                            for (int i=0;i<jsonArray1.length();i++){ login to get data from jsonArray}`. But it gives me an exception like this: `at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:101)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:616)`

Comment: Looks like you're trying to get a JSONObject from a property that is not a JSONObject.  What does the variable 'sub' contain?  Because you pass that into 2 different getXXX() methods.

Comment: sub is basically a subject, so based on that subject selected by user, i can get data of that subject only. For example, if i select Cyber Security(sub1), i should get the data only from that subject(sub1).

Comment: it also gives me this line: `at Computer of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject`.

Comment: So again, there's a mismatch between the type of data you are asking for and what actually exists. If you pass the same value for 'sub' into two different getXXX() methods, it makes sense than one of them is going to throw an exception. A JSON property can't be both a sub object and an array at the same time. You might want to use the optXXX() methods instead of the getXXX() methods. The opt methods don't throw exceptions are better if you are unsure of the data or choices the user is going to make.